# Is there an easy way to extend all the individual interfaces in a union type of these interfaces?

Tags: typescript

I have three different interfaces

```
interface SmallOrder {
  prop1: string
}

interface MediumOrder {
  prop2: string
}

interface LargeOrder {
  prop3: string
}

type Order = SmallOrder | MediumOrder | LargeOrder;

type Res = Order[]

type Country = 'US' | 'International'
```

So Response is, for example, what I get from an API request. After I get the response, however, I need to make another API call to get an attribute of the orders that didn't come in the first one, let's say that attribute is of type `Country`. When I make that request, I will add this attribute to each of the orders I had previously saved. Question is, how can I easily type these new orders.

I want something like below (obviously doesn't work since Order isn't an interface), but I want to have a type that

```
interface OrderWithCountry extends Order {
  country: Country
}

so that it would become something like
type OrderWithCountry = SmallOrderWithCountry | MediumOrderWithCountry | LargeOrderWithCountry
```

Clearly I could define the interfaces `SmallOrderWithCountry`, etc and then define `OrderWithCountry`, but what if I have fifty order types. **Is there an easier way to do it?**

EDIT:
I thought I had a solution with the first answer below, but the issue persists for the example below. In particular, why can't I write the if statement checking `o.common`? I probably need a type guard here but why can't i even just check the property?

```
interface SmallOrder {
  common: string,
  prop1: string
}

interface MediumOrder {
  common: string,
  prop2: string
}

interface LargeOrder {
  common: string,
  prop3: string
}

interface XLargeOrder {
  prop4: number
}

type Order = SmallOrder | MediumOrder | LargeOrder | XLargeOrder;

type Res = Order[]

type Country = 'US' | 'International'

type OrderExt = Order & { country: Country }

const myOrders: Order[] = [
  { common: 'one', prop1: "small" },
  { common: 'two', prop2: "medium" },
  { common: 'three', prop3: "large" },
  { common: 'four', prop1: "smaller" }
]

const myExtOrders: OrderExt[] = myOrders.map(o => ({
  ...o,
  country: 'US'
}))

myExtOrders.map(o => {
  if (o.common) {
    o.common.trim()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding what you want correctly, an [intersection type](https://codingblast.com/typescript-intersection-types/) ([official handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types)) should work.

```
type OrderWithCountry = Order & {
  country: Country
}
```

In the context of typings, `&` is the type intersection operator, combining all the properties from its operands into one new type.

For the second question about the `common` property, TS won't let you use it without a type guard because it doesn't exist on all the types. One way to write and use a type guard is like this (you can modify the names and specific type constraints to suit your real scenario):

```
function isOrderWithCommonProp(o: OrderExt & { common?: string }): o is OrderExt & { common: string } {
  return !!o.common
}

myExtOrders.map(o => {
  if (isOrderWithCommonProp(o)) {
    o.common.trim()
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi, I thought your answer was the final one but actually the issue I have exists still. I've made an EDIT with the exact case in which I get a TS error.

Comment: @evianpring I updated the answer to address your new question